# In a Rails app, how can I have a Tumblr or Wordpress blog live at appname.com/blog instead of blog.appname.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, dns, subdomain, tumblr

I recently read [these notes about SEO](http://melmiranda.com/post/12529167823/seo-tricks-from-patio11-aka-patrick-mckenzie) which say that you loose "Google juice" by having your blog live on a subdomain.

I've currently got a tumblr blog set up on blog.myapp.com. What do I need to do to have the same blog accessible via myapp.com/blog instead?

Comment: do you have an nginx/apache before your app?

Comment: Well I'm on Heroku, so I think I'm pretty limited in what I can change…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the pure ruby solution:

**config/routes.rb**

```
match "/blog(/*path)" => redirect{ |params| "http://www.google.com" + (params[:path] ? "/?q=#{params[:path]}" : '/')}
```

How it works:

- `/blog` goes to http://www.google.com
- `/blog/programming/1234-my-article` goes to http://www.google.com/?q=programming/1234-my-article

If you have an apache/nginx webserver before your app it's better to add an url rewrite rule in your apache/nginx webserver ;)